# How can i create new folder in Tomcat automatically and use it for storing uploaded data?

Tags: java, tomcat

Ok i learn and implement how to upload and retrieve images from a folder on the server machine itself. But the i've implement that in a folder which is itself in my webapp's directory.
I know it is not a good idea but that `image` servlet with path `/image/*` is unable to access folder in directory with `context` path set in `server.xml` .
Codes are :
`Image.java servlet` :

```
public class Image extends HttpServlet {

public static void returnFile(String filename, OutputStream out)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // A FileInputStream is for bytes
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024];  // 4K buffer
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Use a ServletOutputStream because we may pass binary information
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    // Get the file to view
    String file = request.getPathTranslated();

    // No file, nothing to view
    if (file == null) {
        out.println("No file to view");
        return;
    }

    // Get and set the type of the file
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file);
    response.setContentType(contentType);

    // Return the file
    try {
        returnFile(file, out);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print("\n" + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

`context variable:`

```
<Context path="*/photos/users" docBase="G:\myApp\images\users" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
```

What i want is to give an **Arbitrary path** something like */data/users* near my webapp in place of absolute path *G:\myApp\images\users* which is created dynamically on first deployment of webapp on any Tomcat 6.x/7.x server machine and can be used whenever i want to access data inside it..
I hope i am clear with my question.

Comment: Note that this is outside what is allowed by the servlet spec.  This may cause you problems when going multi-host or using another container.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directory using [`File.mkdir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) or [`File.mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).  The first one creates the directory in its designated parent, which must already exist.  The second one also creates parent and "ancestor" directories if required.

Note that your application may not be running with sufficient privilege to create directories or files in arbitrary places.  Also, while `File.mkdirs` can create an number of directories, it can't create things on non-existent Windows drives.  So it is important to check the `boolean` returned by the `mkdir` and `mkdirs` methods.  (And if it is `false`, then there's not much you can do about it!)

---

Having said that, I don't think it is a good idea for a webapp to be using directories outside of the web container, let alone creating them.  As @Thorbjørn's comment implies, this can cause a range of portability and platform issues, and it can limit the deployer's options in deploying your webapp (in general).  There are also concerns with web container sandboxing ... if the deployer chooses to do that.

If you do use the file system for persistence of your webapp's state, then it is a better idea to have the deployer create the base directory by hand.  At least that way he/she knows that it has been created and where it is ... and if he/she gets the pathname wrong the webapp can detect this and refuse to start.  (This also addresses the privilege issue.  It is better for the deployer to run the `mkdir` command with raised privilege than it it so run the web container with raised privilege.)

Comment: `privilege` is a good point..but problem is what if don't know if the server has a existing  directory C:\ or D:\ or E:\ or anything else or what privileges is provided to me there?